# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable when summing up matrix diagonals

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, error-handling

I need help with understanding what in my code is causing the error below:

The whole trace back is here:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18232/558242258.py", line 1, in <module>
    diagonalDifference(arr)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18232/2138727441.py", line 3, in diagonalDifference
    m = sum([arr[i][i] for i in range(n)])

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable


n = int(input().strip()) # n for n*n mat
arr = []
for _ in range(n):
   arr.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))  #takes n times inputs, each time n space separated integer

def diagonalDifference(arr):
        n = len(arr)
        m = sum([arr[i][i] for i in range(n)])
        o = sum([arr[i][n-i-1] for i in range(n)])
        return abs(m-o)
```

thank you

PS. thank you for your suggestion. I saw this suggestion of renaming any possible sum or int variables. but I do not have any of those anywhere in my code.

Comment: Do you have any variables named `sum` or `range` in your code? That would be the only immediate reason I can see for this to happen - you've named a variable one of those two names and shadowed one or other of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kemp said, you are trying to use an `int` as a function in the line your error message points to.

The two keywords you are using as a function are `sum` and `range`. So it is likely you have a line somewhere in your code where you assign an `int` to one of those two keywords.

look for `sum =` or `range =` in your code and rename them.